# Erlang process monitoring itself

Tags: process, erlang, monitor, self

I am trying to create a process in Erlang that can monitor itself and restart of it exits. So far I've had no luck at all, so don't have any code to show. Is this even possible in Erlang, and if so how?

Edit: [J Fritsch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1054808/j-fritsch) posted a link to a [sample](http://blog.plagelao.com/7languages7weeks/erlang/2011/07/17/erlang-day-three.html) that monitors itself but only once. If exit(Doctor, doctor). is used twice it doesn't work the second time. Any ideas on how to get round this?

Comment: You can't use `exit(Doctor, doctor)` twice in [J Fritsch](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1054808/j-fritsch)'s [sample](http://blog.plagelao.com/7languages7weeks/erlang/2011/07/17/erlang-day-three.html) because `Doctor` doesn't contain PID of running doctor process but there is new one.

Comment: Ix there a way round this issue?

Comment: Simply don't do it. If someone kills you process with `exit(Pid, kill)` you can't mask this. Supervisors is way how to deal with restart so use it. J Fritsch's sample is flawed in many other ways.

Comment: I, too, am reading "Seven Languages In Seven Weeks" :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the process doing the monitoring is the one doing the dying, you will invariably get yourself into knots.

Use a supervisor.

Comment: Is there a way to do it though? It's an exercise in a book I'm working through, and I'd like to do it even if it's a bit fiddly.

Comment: Wrap a try-catch around the process's main function and have the function call itself recursively from inside the catch. You'll also have to set trap_exit. I'm not sure, but there may also be ways your process can die that it can't catch.

Comment: Alternatively, get the process to start its own monitoring/restarting process.

Comment: Is there a way to make the monitoring process do the same...? The questions in the book are:
- Make the Doctor process restart itself if it should die.
- Make a monitor for the Doctor monitor. If either monitor dies, restart it.

Where Doctor is a simple process that itself deals with monitoring a different process.

Comment: Which book is this? Once a process has died then it **is** really dead and gone so it can't do anything. You need another process to monitor it. This it the basis of having supervisors and workers.

Comment: The book is "Seven Langauges in Seven Weeks".

Comment: http://blog.plagelao.com/7languages7weeks/erlang/2011/07/17/erlang-day-three.html

Comment: Good shout, but see the edited question; it only manages to revive itself once for some reason.